# Correct format for CDO AddAttachment for UNC path

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, cdo.message

CDO works fine in Access VBA for me except when I try to use UNC paths for the attachments.  According to [MSDN documentation on CDO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526983(VS.85).aspx), AddAttachment should allow UNC paths.  Here's what I think should work, but doesn't:

```
msg1.AddAttachment "\\serv.dom.local\path with spacesh1\file.xls"
```

It works perfectly fine if I use "C:...".  What's the correct format?

The error I get is -2147024894 (80070002).  "The system cannot find the file specified"

UPDATE:  I gave up and created (or copied) the file to my local C drive rather than continue to fool with this.

Answer (score 1):

The UNC format should be:   `\\servername\sharename\path\filename`

Whichever user runs the program would have to have permissions for the sharename

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just use the server name.

i.e.

```
msg1.AddAttachment "\\servername\path with spacesh1\file.xls"
```

Comment: The point is that you need an SMB server name, not a DNS server name. Does it work with the IP address?

Comment: sorry, David - I didn't get a chance to try the IP.  But what's the difference between a SMB name and a UNC using DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Does the user that runs the COM ActiveX has permissions to access that share?

Comment: I gave up on this issue, so no longer want to go back to the environment to try this.  But since I was developing and testing under the same user name; I'm pretty sure that wasn't the problem.